# Jackson @JsonIgnoreProperties not working from super class

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

i have a class named "BaseEntity". other entities extended from Base Entity.

**Base Entity**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"createdBy", "lastModifiedBy", "manager"})
    private User createdBy;

    private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"createdBy", "lastModifiedBy", "manager"})
    private User lastModifiedBy;

    private Instant lastModifiedDate = Instant.now();

    // getters & setters
}
```

**User entity extended from Base Entity.**

```
@Entity
public class User2 extends BaseEntity {

    private String userName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"createdBy", "lastModifiedBy", "manager"})
    private User manager;

    // getters & setters
}
```

**Error**
When i try to serialize user i got this error.

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class a.b.c.d.domain.User]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->a.b.c.d.domain.User["createdBy"])

**if i change only createdBy and lastModifiedBy like this it works. manager user does not cause error**

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private User createdBy;
```

But this time the json does not contain any createdBy or lastModifiedBy info.

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "userName": "admin",
  "manager": {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "system"
  }
}
```

Simply i want to see this json. The first step must contains createdBy and lastModifiedBy.

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "userName": "admin",
  "manager": {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "system"
  },
  "createdBy": {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "system"
  },
  "lastModifiedBy": {
    "id": 2,
    "username": "admin"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use is at the class level.These properties are considered to be ignored in JSON serialization and deserialization.

Example :-

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "bookName", "bookCategory" })
public class Book {
   @JsonProperty("bookId")
   private String id;

   @JsonProperty("bookName")        
   private String name;

   @JsonProperty("bookCategory")    
   private String category;  

}
```

If you want to ignore at field level you can use `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: it works on field level too. Because "manager" field does not cause any error. Error comes only from super class relations.

Comment: why are you using json ignore if you want to include these properties?

Comment: @Crazoute I don't see any problem with your code ! @@

Comment: @Yasham i want these properties only level one. I don't want more lower levels. because other levels cause stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I think @JsonIgnoreProperties should be placed at class level, right before you declare your class.

Comment: if i declare class level @JsonIgnoreProperties json does not contains createdBy and lastModifiedBy even in first level.

Comment: Isn't that the point of `@JsonIgnoreProperties`?

Answer (score 0):

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) try using this above your class name. 
When we pass true to ignoreUnknown element, then in deserialization if JSON data has a field for which there is no logical property then that JSON field will be ignored and no error will be thrown.
Something like this :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Book {
    @JsonProperty("bookId")
    private String id; 
}
```